# Spring Infinispan application not utilising cache in Infinispan cluster

Tags: spring, caching, infinispan

I'm trying to use Spring Caching with Infinispan. I'm using Spring Boot version 3.2.8 and Infinispan version 8.2.4

In my application I've got

```
@Component
@CacheConfig(cacheNames = "rtdm")
public class CacheRepository {

@Cacheable
public String findByCode(String code) {
     ...
}
```

I'm using infinispan-spring4-embedded so then I've got

```
spring.cache.infinispan.config=infinispan.xml
```

in my properties file and then the following in my infinispan.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<infinispan>

   <jgroups>
       <stack-file name="udp" path="jgroups.xml" />
   </jgroups>

   <cache-container default-cache="rtdm">
      <transport stack="udp" node-name="${nodeName}" />
      <replicated-cache name="rtdm"/>
   </cache-container>
</infinispan>
```

The cache actually appears to be working in that the with the first call the method is called and subsequent it doesn't - that's good.
However, I'm not convinced it's actually using the RTDM cache that I've setup in the cluster as when I look in JMX all the attributes show 0 operations.
Just to be clear I'm using standalone mode for my cluster and I've added the following to my clustered.xml file

```
<cache-container name="rtdm-container" default-cache="rtdm">
    <transport lock-timeout="60000"/>
    <replicated-cache mode="SYNC" name="rtdm" start="EAGER"/>
</cache-container>
```

I believe in my two node cluster my infinispan instances are communicating with each other as the logs indicated this to be the case.
Am I going in the correct direction, or can anyone spot something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you add @EnableCaching to your configuration bean?

Comment: Thanks, yes I did. The caching is working, I'm just not convinced it's utilising the one that I setup in the infinispan cluster.

Comment: You can use one of my code snippets to validate it (https://github.com/slaskawi/presentations/blob/master/2016_devconf/antifroud-checker/src/main/java/org/infinispan/microservices/caching/CacheInspector.java). Just invoke it periodically and check if the caches fill in.